# Office js API setDataAsync not working as suggested in Document

Tags: office-js

I am devloping a word add in which has usecase to insert Rich Text Format in Binding.My Binding Type is 'Text' and i have also set coercionType as 'Html' still it is not replacing in binding.My host application is word online.Whereas,this is working in word desktop application.But i want it in word online.
Please suggest .
Thanks

```
    /*
    *addBindingToData
    *@param userSelectedText -- is a string selected in word document
    */
    function addBindingToData(userSelectedText) {
        var bindVariableIdPrefix = userSelectedText + '_Binding';
        Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync(Office.BindingType.Text, {
            id: bindVariableIdPrefix + '__' + count
        }, function(asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.log('Action failed. Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Added new binding with type: ' + asyncResult.value.type + ' and id: ' + asyncResult.value.id);
                getVarArrayOnSelection(asyncResult.value.id,userSelectedText, bindVariableIdPrefix).then(function(bindings) {
                    createInputboxes(bindings);
                });
            }
        });
        count++;
    }
Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(obj.id,function(asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.log('Action failed. Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                console.log(asyncResult.value.id+'got Id');
                var BindingId = asyncResult.value;
                BindingId.setDataAsync("<b>Hello</b> World!", {coercionType: "html"}, function (asyncResult) {
                    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                        console.log('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8TzR.png)
[One Drive Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkO8z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I was able to repro this issue and know the root cause.

The long story short is this: when a binding is created in the document what effectively happens is that a new content control is added to the document. Depending on the selection of the user at the time the binding is created, a type of content control is created, it can be either:

1. **BLOCK** content control:  If the selection includes a complete paragraph or paragraphs a **BLOCK** content control is created. On this cases the HTML insertion is successful (which is what I was trying).

   2. **INLINE** content Control: On the other hand, If the selection is a partial selection (within a paragraph without fully selecting it) then an **INLINE** content control is created. In this case the HTML insertion fails.

The good news is that this is a known issue, we are working on enabling this in the near future.

I am leaving the original answer as reference.
thanks!
================= ORIGINAL ANSWER ============================

I was trying your code in Word Online **but I was not able to repro** this issue. I can see the HTML correctly printed in the document.

Have a couple of questions:

1. Can you please add the code you used to create the binding?
2. Also are you trying this in OneDrive for consumer or OneDrive for Business. That will be really helpful to investigate in more detail.

Thanks!
Juan.

Comment: OneDrive for Business or OneDrive for consumer ?

Comment: I am using to **onedrive for Business** for saving the document.

Comment: Ok, let's try another question. When you log into OneDrive you so with a hotmail or outlook.com accounts or your organization's (school, work) account ?

Comment: Hi juan ,I have added the code of create binding .   what i am doing is on user selection  of variable in document, i am taking the variable and creating a binding on the variable , then creating a text box corresponding to variable in addin . This text box will allow user to type what ever string he wants to replace in variable

Comment: in word document.when user type a normal text it is replacing no issues in that, but when it is a case of Rich Text it is not replacing .Throwing error that 'this operation is not supported in this host'.I am using word online and as per your setDataAsync Documentation it should support in word online.This issue is working fine in word desktop app.Another thing the document is stored in onedrive.

Comment: Yes. It is supported. What I am trying to find out is if you are using OneDrive for Consumer or One Drive for business. Please answer my last question. Thx

Comment: I log into OneDrive through **outlook account**.user id of account is lalit@wittyparrot.com

Comment: Ok. Thanks! In what location is this?

Comment: Bangalore,India

Comment: Ok thanks let me investigate. I am assuming this is office365 or this is an on premise environment?

Comment: Hi juan...can you able to reproduce the problem...?

Comment: No I was not. I tried your code in both One Drive for Business and for Consumer and its working in both. I am not sure what's going on with your tenant but seems corrupted. Can you try your code in OneDrive for consumer?.

Comment: Hi Juan,Thanks for your suggestion.I tried with normal one drive.But still the problem exits.I have added two pics.Please check.Give some further suggestions.thanks

Comment: Hello I was able to repro. see my edited answer for details.

Comment: Thanks juan...i will check as suggested.