# word.run did not work in server enviroment

Tags: office-js

Bindings object (Word)

URL: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.bindings

1. Creating binding to variables:

   - Using Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(), asyncResult.value (the response) is added with a TextBinding using
     Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync() to the current selection
2. Populating content

   - Using Binding.setDataAsync method we are writing data to the bound section of the document represented by the specified binding object.
     The issue at this point is we are unable to set {coercionType: "html"} to insert rich text at the bound section of the document, it works with text.

Issues:

1. Unable to insert rich text using setDataAsync() in Online word
2. Unable to make an active selection of the content using bindingId which will help us to use Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync() which writes data to the current selection in the document (Rich text works with this API). We need to release the binding before using this method.
3. Unable to execute by passing a function into the Word.run() method after Office.initialize
   Word.run(function (context) { });

There are no console errors or warning, but Word.run() block never runs when tried to execute the code over the server. Local dev environment works in this case.

[Error Reference Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfmLe.png)

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <!-- BeginBasicSettings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided -->

  <!--IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you clone this manifest ensure that you change this id to your own GUID -->
  <Id>010861c8-0558-472c-b350-f7795e27cfa5</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Parrot365 : [QA]</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various placed of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Parrot365 : [QA]" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Parrot365 : QA Mode"/>

  <!--Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com/resources/assets/images/wp_logo_32px.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com/resources/assets/images/wp_logo_128px.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://support.wittyparrot.com/support/home" />

  <!--BeginTaskpaneMode integration. Office 2013 and any client that doesn't understand commands will use this section.
    This section will also be used if there are no VersionOverrides -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com?source=msoffice" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <!--EndTaskpaneMode integration -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <!--BeginAddinCommandsMode integration-->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- Optional, override the description of the Add-in -->
    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
    <!--Required, hosts node. Each host can have a different set of commands -->
    <Hosts>
      <!--Specific host. Workbook=Excel, Document=Word, Presentation=PowerPoint -->
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in.
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
                        <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
                        <Title resid="Witty.GetStarted.Title"/>

                        <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
                        <Description resid="Witty.GetStarted.Description"/>

                        <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL.
                            resid points to a Url resource -->
                        <LearnMoreUrl resid="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your companyname-->
              <Group id="Witty.Citations.Group1Id1">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="residLabel4" />
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                 <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3Id1">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="residLabel3" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="residLabel" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon3_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the taskpane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>

      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in.
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
                        <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
                        <Title resid="Witty.GetStarted.Title"/>

                        <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
                        <Description resid="Witty.GetStarted.Description"/>

                        <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL.
                            resid points to a Url resource -->
                        <LearnMoreUrl resid="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your companyname-->
              <Group id="Witty.Citations.Group1Id1">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="residLabel4" />
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                 <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3Id1">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="residLabel3" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="residLabel" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon3_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the taskpane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>

      <Host xsi:type="Presentation">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

          <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in.
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
                        <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
                        <Title resid="Witty.GetStarted.Title"/>

                        <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
                        <Description resid="Witty.GetStarted.Description"/>

                        <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL.
                            resid points to a Url resource -->
                        <LearnMoreUrl resid="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your companyname-->
              <Group id="Witty.Citations.Group1Id1">
                <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="residLabel4" />
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                 <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button3Id1">
                  <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                  <Label resid="residLabel3" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                    <Title resid="residLabel" />
                     <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon3_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the taskpane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="residUnitConverterUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon1_16x16" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com/resources/assets/images/widget_logo.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="icon1_32x32" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com/resources/assets/images/wp_logo_32px.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="icon1_80x80" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com/resources/assets/images/wp_logo_80px.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="icon2_32x32" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com/resources/assets/images/wp_logo_32px.png">
        </bt:Image>
        <bt:Image id="icon3_32x32" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com/resources/assets/images/wp_logo_32px.png">
        </bt:Image>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
         <bt:Url id="residDesktopFuncUrl" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com?source=msoffice">
        </bt:Url>
        <bt:Url id="residUnitConverterUrl" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com?source=msoffice">
        </bt:Url>
          <!--LearnMore URL currently not used -->
        <bt:Url id="Witty.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://qaparrot365.wittyparrot.com">
        </bt:Url>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="residLabel" DefaultValue="Launch Widget">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="residLabel3" DefaultValue="Parrot365">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="residLabel4" DefaultValue=" ">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="Witty.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Parrot365 Widget Loaded Successfully">
        </bt:String>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="residToolTip" DefaultValue="Parrot365 add-in provides improves productivity, accuracy and consistency in communication.">
        </bt:String>
         <bt:String id="Witty.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Get going by opening the Home tab on the Ribbon then click Parrot365 button">
        </bt:String>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

```js
'use strict';
var count = 0;
(function() {

 angular.module('wpoffice')
  .directive('wittyWordVariable', function() {

   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/components/witty-word-variable/witty-word-variable_template.html',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: true,
    controller: 'WordVariableController',
    controllerAs: 'WordVariableCtrl'
   };
  })
  .controller('WordVariableController', WordVariableController);

 function WordVariableController($q, ngNotify) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.init = init;
  vm.getSelectedWordFromDocument = getSelectedWordFromDocument;
  vm.populateWordVar = populateWordVar;

  function init() {
            console.log('Initialized WordVariableController');
   vm.inputBoxObjects = [];
   vm.varValues = [];
   vm.onloadVariablesFound = [];
   if (Office.context.document) {
    getAllSelectedContentControl();
   } else {
    ngNotify.set('Please reload Parrot365', 'error');
   }
  }

        /*
        *getAllSelectedContentControl----it will load the variable and  corresponding text box
        *@param --- no param
        */
  function getAllSelectedContentControl() {
            console.log('getAllSelectedContentControl');
            console.log(Word);
            Word.run(function(context) {
                console.log('inside getSelectedContentControl 2');
                    var thisDocument = context.document;
                    context.load(thisDocument, 'contentControls/id, contentControls/text, contentControls/tag');
                    return context.sync().then(function() {
                        console.log('returned getSelectedContentControl');
                        if (thisDocument.contentControls.items.length !== 0) {
                            console.log(thisDocument.contentControls.items.length);
                            for (var i = 0; i < thisDocument.contentControls.items.length; i++) {
                                var variableLabel = thisDocument.contentControls.items[i].text;
                                var tagId = thisDocument.contentControls.items[i].tag;
                                if (tagId) {
                                    getVarArray(variableLabel,tagId).then(function(arrayObj) {
                                        createInputboxes(arrayObj);
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('Content is empty');
                        }
                    });
                }).then(function() {
                    console.log('completed');
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error);
                    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                        console.log('Error code and message: ' + error.toString());
                    }
                });
  }




        /*
        *getVarArray----creates object on load
        *@param variablevalue---value of variable
        *@param  TagId -----id of variable
        */
  function getVarArray(variablevalue,tagId)
        {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var allBindings = [];
            var tagPrefix, variableLabel;

    if (tagId && tagId.lastIndexOf("__") != -1) {
     tagPrefix = tagId.substr(0,tagId.lastIndexOf('__'));
                    var index = tagId.indexOf("_");
                    if(index) {
                        variableLabel = tagId.substr(0,index);
                    }
    }

    var temp = {
     'id': tagId,
     'variableLabel': variableLabel,
     'tagPrefix': tagPrefix,
                    'value': variablevalue
    };

    var indexOfBinding = _.findIndex(allBindings, {
     variableLabel: variableLabel,
     tagPrefix: tagPrefix
    });

    if (indexOfBinding === -1) {
     allBindings.push(temp);
    }

    deferred.resolve(allBindings);

   return deferred.promise;
  }

        /*
        *createInputboxes ----call createVariable function which will create scope obj
        */
  function createInputboxes(arrayOfBindinds)
        {
   angular.forEach(arrayOfBindinds, function(binding) {
    console.log(binding);
                var textBoxValue = binding.value ? binding.value:'Enter Text';
                console.log(binding.variableLabel+'===='+binding.tagPrefix+'===='+textBoxValue+'===='+binding.id);
    createVariable (binding.variableLabel,binding.tagPrefix,textBoxValue,binding.id);
   });
  }



  /*getSelectedWord - Get Selected Data from the document which  user has  selected manually.
   *@no param
   *called on user selection
   *
   */
  function getSelectedWordFromDocument()
        {
            console.log('abc');
         Word.run(function(context) {
            console.log('inside word.run');
   var range = context.document.getSelection();
   var ContentControlForSelection = range.insertContentControl();
   ContentControlForSelection.load('text');
   return context.sync().then(function() {
    var variableLabel = ContentControlForSelection.text;
    var tagPrefix = variableLabel + '_tag';
    ContentControlForSelection.tag = tagPrefix + '__' + count;
    //var conditionalVariable = 'Onseletion';
    //createVariable(variableLabel, tagPrefix);
                console.log('variable created with'+variableLabel);
                getVarArrayOnSelection(ContentControlForSelection.tag,variableLabel, tagPrefix).then(function(bindings) {
                    console.log(bindings);
                    createInputboxes(bindings);
                });

   });

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Error: ' + error);
   if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
    console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
   }
  });
    }



        /*
        *getVarArrayOnSelection --- it creates obj for selected word in document
        *@param--tagId
        *@param--userSelectedText
        *@param--tagPrefix
        */
  function getVarArrayOnSelection(tagId,userSelectedText,tagPrefix)
        {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var allBindings = [];

   var temp = {
                'id': tagId,
    'variableLabel': userSelectedText,
    'tagPrefix': tagPrefix
   };

   var indexOfBinding = _.findIndex(allBindings, {
    variableLabel: userSelectedText,
    tagPrefix: tagPrefix
   });
   if (indexOfBinding === -1) {
    allBindings.push(temp);
   }

   deferred.resolve(allBindings);
   return deferred.promise;
  }


  function createVariable(variableLabel, tagPrefix, newValue, id) {
            console.log(variableLabel+'===='+ tagPrefix+'===='+ newValue+'===='+ id);
   var flag = false;
   var inputObj = {
    id: id,
    label: variableLabel,
    tag: tagPrefix,
    value: newValue
   };

   if (vm.inputBoxObjects.length > 0) {
    var index = _.findIndex(vm.inputBoxObjects, {
     label: variableLabel
    });
    if (index === -1) {
     vm.inputBoxObjects.push(inputObj);
    } else {
     console.log('it already exists in the array');
    }
   } else {
    vm.inputBoxObjects.push(inputObj);
   }
  }

  /*populateWordVar
   *@TextBoxId = Text Box Id
   *@tagPrefix = unique identifier
   **/
  function populateWordVar(obj, $event, $index)
        {
   console.log(obj);
            var TextboxValue = ($event.target.value === '' ? obj.label : $event.target.value);

            console.log(TextboxValue);

            Word.run(function (context) {

                var contentControlsWithTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag(obj.id);

                context.load(contentControlsWithTag, 'text');

                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    if (contentControlsWithTag.items.length === 0) {
                        console.log("There isn't a content control with a tag in this document.");
                    } else {
                        console.log('The first content control with the tag has this text: ' + contentControlsWithTag.items[0].text);
                        for (var i = 0;i<contentControlsWithTag.items.length;i++){
                        contentControlsWithTag.items[i].insertHtml(TextboxValue, 'Replace');
                        }
                    }
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
            });
  }




 }
})();
```

```html
<div class="flex layout-column pad-box-10 profile-container" ng-init="WordVariableCtrl.init()">

  <div class="layout-row">
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" ng-click="WordVariableCtrl.getSelectedWordFromDocument ()">
        <span class="ms-Button-label">Create Variable</span>
      </button>
  </div>

  <div class="layout-row">
    <div class="layout-column">
      <div ng-if="WordVariableCtrl.inputBoxObjects.length > 0" class="layout-row flex layout-align-start-center margin-d-10" id="innerDiv" data-ng-repeat="inputBox in WordVariableCtrl.inputBoxObjects">
        <label class="ms-Label margin-r-10" for="{{inputBox.id}}" style="width:40%;overflow: hidden;display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">{{inputBox.label}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter value" value="{{inputBox.value}}" id={{inputBox.id}} ng-blur="WordVariableCtrl.populateWordVar(inputBox,$event,$index)" class="ms-TextField-field flex flex-rem send-email-input">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more details.  What is the code that is failing? What is it failing with? What is "server" (is it Office 365, or on-prem?...)

Comment: When the project is being served from Gulp locally, it works fine. But when the same code is deployed over Apache server, Word.run() block never executes, There are no console errors or warnings to trace.

Comment: Without an error message or seeing the code that is failing, there isn't much to go on. Please post your manifest, snippet of the code that is failing and any errors logged on the server.

Comment: Hi Marc,Thanks for suggestion.Really appreciatee that.I will surely work on your suggestion.I have added my full code snippets too.Please have a look.Please suggest any solution you have.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest is declaring your add-in works with Word, PowerPoint and Excel but the code it points to is leveraging the Word Api. You should ensure your manifest declares a dependency on Word API and remove Excel and PowerPoint. This will ensure the add-in only shows up where it is supported.

The code is heavily minified making it difficult to sort out exactly what it is doing. I suspect your issue here is that you're making calling using Word API 1.3 or 1.4 which are not supported with Word Online yet. This would explain why you are seeing correct behavior using Word on your desktop but not when used with Word Online. I would suggest looking at the code to ensure you're not pulling a dependency on any [new methods introduced with 1.3](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets#whats-new-in-word-javascript-api-13).

You're also passing params into the app from your manifest. Your add-in's source page should not rely on parameters. The guidance here is to use a unique landing page for your add-in. You can redirect the user to a new URI after the add-in as initialized and the communication channels between Word and the add-in have been established.

Comment: Actually how i solved this keeping my word addin  file outside the build files.It start working.I use gulp for build.After build it didn't identify word.run.

Comment: so i put it outside buid file .so that it didn't get minified and sanitized

Answer (score 0):

regarding the set data I already answered this in your other question: [Office js API setDataAsync not working as suggested in Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959180/office-js-api-setdataasync-not-working-as-suggested-in-document)